# DRF translating my url signature from %2B to '+'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-storage

There seems to be a bug in the way DRF renders hyper-linked URL's in the Self describing API. DRF is translating my url signature for S3 (django-storage) from %2B to '+' when being displayed. However `format=json` does not have this translation issue.

For example:

This is the Serializer:

```
class CatalogueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    image = HyperlinkedImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = CatalogueItem
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'image')
```

HyperlinkedImageField:

```
class HyperlinkedImageField(serializers.ImageField):
    def to_native(self, value):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if value:
            url = request.build_absolute_uri(value.url)
        else:
            url = 'null'
        return url
```

Value of the URL is correct and the signature is right. However when DRF renders the URL it changes the Signature from this....

**Good**

```
Signature=lMG4NLl51IHeXWCU%2B2GPBN1vU30%3D&Expires=1404604768
```

to this:

**Bad**

```
Signature=lMG4NLl51IHeXWCU+2GPBN1vU30=&Expires=1404604768
```

Where the only difference is the translation of `%2B to '+'`.

I have tried to get around the following in my serializer:

```
def transform_image(self, obj, value):
        return urllib.quote(value, safe="%/:=&?~#+!$,;'@()*[]")
```

But, no matter, it always does the translation of %2B to '+'.

Is there a work around?

Comment: Apparently it also translates `%3D` into `=`, so the URL gets properly and completely decoded when rendered.

Comment: I think you should try and use **urlquote** and **iri_to_uri**, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#taking-care-in-get-absolute-url).  Let me know if that works.

Comment: perhaps this helps: http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap whatever string you want in "slugify": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify

That makes sure that the string is always "URL safe"